# Reflection - get locally defined variables?

Tags: php, reflection

Is it possible to get **local** (not [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) or `static`) variables too with Reflection, like this?

```
function getVars()
{
   ...
   ...
   ...Reflection codes...
   ...
   ...
}


function my1()
{
   $x = 5;
   ...
   $y = $smth_calculated;
   ...
   getVars();
}
```

so, in `getVars` I was able to get values of `$x` and `$y`.

---

EDIT: I really have no idea (..but I have), why the question has `-4 downvotes & close` flags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is a tricky thing :). I really don't know why would you need such a function but, it can be done with a bit of work. Of course this is just my simple solution which could be improved to fulfill all your needs.

First of all using the ReflectionFunction object you could access the static variables very easy, but not the internal ones. The static ones would be accessible like:

```
function getVars($function)
{
    $reflectionFunction = new ReflectionFunction($function);

    return $reflectionFunction->getStaticVariables();
}

function my1()
{
   static $x = 5;

   $vars = getVars(__FUNCTION__);

   var_dump($vars);
}

my1();
```

The `$vars` value would look like:

```
array(1) {
  ["x"]=>
  &int(5)
}
```

Now, there is an workaround to get the other variables too. I will use a simple regular expression to match the variables but be aware that it must be improved a lot.

```
function getVars($function=null)
{
    if(!$function) $function = debug_backtrace()[1]['function'];
    $reflectionFunction = new ReflectionFunction($function);

    // Open the function file.
    $file = new SplFileObject($reflectionFunction->getFileName());
    $file->seek($reflectionFunction->getStartLine() + 1);

    // Grab the function body.
    $content = '';
    while ($file->key() < $reflectionFunction->getEndLine() - 1) {
        $content .= $file->current();
        $file->next();
    }

    // Match all the variables defined.
    preg_match_all('/\$([\w]+)\s?=\s?(.*);/', $content, $matches);

    return array_combine($matches[1] ?? [], $matches[2] ?? []);
}

function my1()
{
   static $x = 5;
   $y = $smth_calculated; 

   var_dump( getVars() );
}

my1();
```

The `$vars` value would look like:

```
array(3) {
  'x' =>
  string(1) "5"
  'y' =>
  string(19) "$smth_calculated" 
}
```

Comment: I've a bit updated my question - so, in the end, there is no way to get `non-static` variables right? and even more, with evaluated `$value` ?  I will tell why I need that.

Comment: Well afaik there is no way to do that.. I never needed such thing, but maybe with a bit more research you could find something more about it

Comment: Ok, if you'd like (just I dont want to change again your answer, but will be nice) if you made a bit more modification, as I've gone a bit further and have a better code, see here:  https://ideone.com/IBNN2p (it's results show below that code).  If you'd integrate that changes, could be a better answer. thanks.  (there is a slight problem, with php 5.6 your  double  `??` triggers error).